# Architecture: Modifying the model in different ways

Tags: c++, qt, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

### Problem statement

I have a model class that looks something like (*extremely* simplified; some members and many, many methods omitted for clarity):

```
class MyModelItem
{
public:
    enum ItemState
    {
        State1,
        State2
    };

    QString text() const;

    ItemState state() const;

private:
    QString _text;

    ItemState _state;
}
```

It is a core element of the application and is used in many different parts of the code:

- It is serialized/deserialized into/from various file formats
- It can be written into or read from a database
- It can be updated by an 'import', that reads a file and applies changes to the currently loaded in-memory model
- It can be updated by the user through various GUI functions

The problem is, this class is has grown over the years and now has several thousands lines of code; it has become a prime example of how to violate the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

It has methods for setting the 'text', 'state', etc. directly (after deserialization) and the same set of methods for setting them from within the UI, which has side effects like updating the 'lastChangedDate' and 'lastChangedUser' etc. Some methods or groups of methods exist even more than twice, with everyone of them doing basically the same thing but slightly different.

When developing new parts of the application, you are very likely using the wrong of the five different ways of manipulating `MyModelItem`, which makes it extremely time consuming and frustrating.

### Requirements

Given this historically grown and overly complex class, the goal is to separate all different concerns of it into different classes, leaving only the core data members in it.

Ideally, I would prefer a solution where a `MyModelItem` object has nothing but `const` members for accessing the data and modifications can only be made using special classes.

Every one of these special classes could then contain an actual concrete implementation of the business logic (a setter of 'text' could do something like *"if the text to be set begins with a certain substring and the state equals 'State1', set it to 'State2'"*).

### First part of the solution

For loading and storing the whole model, which consists of many `MyModelItem` objects and some more, the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) looks like a promising solution. I could implement several visitor classes for different file formats or database schemas and have a `save` and `load` method in `MyModelItem`, which accept such a visitor object each.

### Open question

When the user enters a specific text, I want to validate that input. The same validation must be made if the input comes from another part of the application, which means I can not move the validation into the UI (in any case, UI-only-validation is often a bad idea). But if the validation happens in the `MyModelItem` itself, I have two problems again:

- The separation of concerns, which was the goal to begin with is negated. All the business logic code is still 'dumped' into the poor model.
- When called by other parts of the application, this validation has to look differently. Implementing different validating-setter-methods is how it is done right now, which has a bad code smell.

It is clear now that the validation has to be moved outside both the UI and the model, into some sort of controller (in a MVC sense) class or collection of classes. These should then decorate/visit/etc the actual dumb model class with its data.

**Which software design pattern fits best to the described case, to allow for different ways of modifying the instances of my class?**

I am asking, because none of the patterns I know solves my problem entirely and I feel like I'm missing something here...

Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Comment: +1 for nice-structured question. Short answer: I prefer separated validator service used for this object. And it can use Composition over Inheritance to implement it's own "Validate()" method.

Comment: Have you thought about the use of the Decorator pattern, to add behaviour to an object without the object being changed directly? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: @Merlin069: the Decorator pattern was one of our first ideas, but the memory overhead was not acceptable (there are millions of instances of this class, which would then grow if we needed one or more decorators per instance). Also, the decorator seems more suitable for reading operations than for mutation operations in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you don't state it explicitly, refactoring thousands of lines of code is a daunting task, and I imagine that some incremental process is preferred over an all-or-nothing one.

Furthermore, the compiler should help as much as possible to detect errors. If it is a lot of work and frustration now to figure out which methods should be called, it will be even worse if the API has been made uniform.

Therefore, I would propose to use the [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), mostly for this reason:

> wrap a poorly designed collection of APIs with a single well-designed API (as per task needs)

Because that is basically what you have: a collection of APIs in one class, that needs to be separated into different groups. Each group would get its own Facade, with its own calls. So the current MyModelItem, with all its carefully crafted different method invocations over the years:

```
...
void setText(String s);
void setTextGUI(String s); // different name
void setText(int handler, String s); // overloading
void setTextAsUnmentionedSideEffect(int state);
...
```

becomes:

```
class FacadeInternal {
    setText(String s);
}
class FacadeGUI {
    setTextGUI(String s);
}
class FacadeImport {
    setText(int handler, String s);
}
class FacadeSideEffects {
    setTextAsUnmentionedSideEffect(int state);
}
```

If we remove the current members in MyModelItem to MyModelItemData, then we get:

```
class MyModelItem {
    MyModelItemData data;

    FacadeGUI& getFacade(GUI client) { return FacadeGUI::getInstance(data); }
    FacadeImport& getFacade(Importer client) { return FacadeImport::getInstance(data); }
}

GUI::setText(MyModelItem& item, String s) {
    //item.setTextGUI(s);
    item.getFacade(this).setTextGUI(s);
}
```

Of course, implementation variants exist here. It could equally well be:

```
GUI::setText(MyModelItem& item, String s) {
    myFacade.setTextGUI(item, s);
}
```

That is more dependent on restrictions on memory, object creation, concurrency, etc. The point is that up till now, it is all straight forward (I won't say search-and-replace), and the compiler helps every step of the way to catch errors.

The nice thing about the Facade is that it can form an interface to multiple libraries/classes. After splitting things up, the business rules are all in several Facades, but you can refactor them further:

```
class FacadeGUI {
    MyModelItemData data;
    GUIValidator validator;
    GUIDependentData guiData;

    setTextGUI(String s) {
        if (validator.validate(data, s)) {
            guiData.update(withSomething)
            data.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

and the GUI code won't have to be changed one bit.

After all that you might choose to normalize the Facades, so that they all have the same method names. It isn't necessary, though, and for clarity's sake it might even be better to keep the names distinct. Regardless, once again the compiler will help validate any refactoring.

(I know I stress the compiler bit a lot, but in my experience, once everything has the same name, and works through one or more layers of indirection, it becomes a pain to find out where and when something is actually going wrong.)

Anyway, this is how I would do it, as it allows for splitting up large chunks of code fairly quickly, in a controlled manner, without having to think too much. It provides a nice stepping stone for further tweaking. I guess that at some point the MyModelItem class should be renamed to MyModelItemMediator.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: If my solution to talk with the customer is not possible, then would I go for your solution, because it is the most flexible one. A class serving more purposes then originally intended can be best split up in different classes to regain the singular responsibility principle for each class. A facade makes that possible.

Comment: Talking with the customer and refactoring don't need to be mutual exclusive. From the problem description, I am not sure that they are already at the "end of the line." As such, the application is still a huge resource wrt the problem domain and specific solutions therein. After some initial refactoring, it can be utilized to start concrete talks with the client about what works, and which parts should be redesigned to anticipate future development. And yes, at this point I think flexibility and keeping options open is important.

Comment: Refactoring a part of an application that has gone out of control for a long time is not always worth the effort. I have never been in that situation without the need of a conversion of data. Most often is the underlying problem that the data model is out of sync. Refactoring a part of the application let that problem go untouched. I upvoted your answer because I think it is the best solution if talking to the customer is not possible, but I know from experience that it is mutually exclusive. The cause is the data model being out of sync with reality. Refactoring does not solve that problem.

Comment: If the data model is outdated, then refactoring won't solve it, no. But separating the core data model from all kinds of other concerns will help in determining whether it is outdated, or not, and how much. So what I meant is that refactoring may bring some control back, and be a better starting point for talks than "the application is totally out of control."

Comment: I agree with you that separation of concerns is a good step. I don't think that we really disagree. My first sentence in the previous comment should read 'that if it is out of control then..'. With regards to this application I do not know (I started my answer with 'If I understand..'). I would adjust my starting point for talks based on the contact with the customer. Since I don't know, I can't say anything about it and only answer theoretically. That is more black and white compared to the colourful reality. Without contradiction can I say that I fully agree with your last comment.

Comment: This approach looks very promising, thanks a lot for your answer! I like it when the compiler can support/verify refactoring steps.

Comment: You're very welcome. Reading your responses to @LoekBergman, that is more or less the situation I had in mind when I wrote this. Not an end-solution in itself, but preparation for functional analysis/redesign stages. Very nice that you can do this in cooperation with the client. I agree with Loek that it sounds like you're handling the project well. Once again, good luck with it!

Answer (score 6):

Plain [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern seems the best strategy to me.

What I understand from your statement is that:

1. The **model** is mutable.
2. the mutation may happen through different **source**. (ie. different classes)
3. the model must validate each mutation effort.
4. Depending on the source of an effort the validation **process** differs.
5. the **model is oblivious of the source and the process**. its prime concern is the state of object it is modeling.

### Proposal:

1. let the **Source** be the classes which somehow mutate the model. it may be the deserializers, the UI, the importers etc.
2. let a **validator** be an interface/super-class which holds a basic logic of validation. it can have methods like : `validateText(String), validateState(ItemState)`...
3. Every **Source** *has-a* **validator**. That validator may be an instance of the base-validator or may inherit and override some of its methods.
4. Every **validator** *has-a* reference to the **model**.
5. A source first sets its own validator then takes the mutation attempt.

now,

```
Source1                   Model                  Validator
   |     setText("aaa")     |                        |
   |----------------------->|    validateText("aaa") |
   |                        |----------------------->|
   |                        |                        |
   |                        |       setState(2)      |
   |          true          |<-----------------------|
   |<-----------------------|                        |
```

the behavior of different validators might be different.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That might be exactly what I was searching for. I started implementing the visitor pattern for all importer/exporters and the strategy pattern for the different mutators (e.g. via the UI).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, then would I not decide yet which design pattern to chose. I think that I have seen code like this several times before and the main problem in my point of view was always that change was build upon change build upon change. 
The class had lost is original purpose and was now serving multiple purposes, which were all not clearly defined and set. The result is a big class (or a big database, spaghetti code etc), which seems to be indispensable yet is a nightmare for maintenance.

The big class is the symptom of a process that is gone out of control. It is where you can see it happen, but my guess is that when this class has been recovered that a lot of other classes will be the first to redesign. If I am correct, then is there also a lot of data corruption, because in a lot of cases is the definition of the data unclear.

My advice would be go back to your customer, talk about the business processes, reorganize the project management of the application and try to find out if the application is still serving the business process well. It might be not - I have been in this type of situation several times in different organizations.
If the business process is understood and the data model is converted in line with the new data model, then can you replace the application with a new design, which is much easier to create. The big class that now exists, does not have to be reorganized anymore, because its reason for existence is gone.
It costs money, but the maintenance now costs also money. A good indication for redesign is if new features are not implemented anymore, because it has become too expensive or error prone to execute.

Comment: I agree: go back to the customer, talk about how it all needs to change. In theory. In practice, the customer will usually tell you that they already paid you to solve all this, that they handed you the requirements, that it was your job to do it well, and quite frankly, that they don't have the budget for making changes that won't add any functionality. If you play your cards right, you can get some compensation for refactoring, but usually it's more a decision about immediate cost versus long term pay-off for the software creator. Clients don't want to pay more for what already works.

Comment: @Jer: In the majority of cases you are absolutely right. However, I have had several assignments with a similar problem and the task to solve it. Your last sentence is the crux: it can end working. One time was the assignment to find out who was the real problem owner: the client or the company I worked for. That was tricky. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Going back to the customer is something we already did. now we first need to restructure the core code and separate different concerns which can then concretely be updated to the clients business problem. All the different operations must remain (loading/saving, importing/exporting, modifying via UI etc.) but they are totally mixed up into one spaghetti-class. And you are absolutely right, there is already data corruption. Furthermore, it has become nearly impossible to add new functionalities or even change the existing one...

Comment: To be exactly, what we try to do is something between refactoring and redesigning: first separating the mess, analyzing what the respective functionalities *should* do (this part of the code was written by a different company) and then simplifying and correcting things. The interface of the class may change here is well, as it is only used within our own application and we can change all dependant code as well.

Comment: I have once shown to a customer in a presentation that his business model had changed over the years, but his data model hadn't. That created a long term problem, because the data could not fit in properly. The customer organization admitted it, but did not change anything. Cause was an internal struggle for power in which the good data at the wrong place was helping on of the directors in his struggle for power. That was the main cause for the trouble in the application. Very interesting to see being external, but it was very frustrating for a lot of people working in the organization.

Comment: The solution of a facade provided by @Jer is a good one imo. Being a facade will then be the only responsibility of that class. Did you get time to create functional documentation of the code? As a software engineer was I always more interested in the why something was done then the how it was done. I could see the latter, but it was sometimes a real puzzle to understand which purpose it served in the first place. Good luck with your project! It looks good how you are handling the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give you a different perspective of the situation you have. Please note that **explanations are written in my own words** for the simplicity's sake. However, terms mentioned are from the enterprise application architecture patterns.

You are designing the business logic of the application. So, `MyModelItem` must be some kind of a business entity. I would say it's the `Active Record` you have.

> **Active Record**: business entity that can CRUD itself, and can manage
>   the business logic related to itself.

The business logic contained in the Active Record has increased and has become hard to manage. That's **very typical** situation with Active Records. This is where you must switch from the Active Record pattern to the `Data Mapper` pattern.

> **Data Mapper**: mechanism (typically a class) managing the mapping (typically between the entity and the data it translates from/to). It
>   starts existing when the mapping concerns of the Active Record are so
>   mature that they need to be put into the separate class. Mapping becomes a logic on its own.

So, here we came to the obvious solution: create a Data Mapper for the `MyModelItem` entity. Simplify the entity so that it does not handle the mapping of itself. Migrate the mapping management to the Data Mapper.

If the `MyModelItem` takes part in the inheritance, consider creating an abstract Data Mapper and concrete Data Mappers for each concrete class you want to map in a different way.

Several notes on how I would implement it:

- Make entity aware of a mapper.
- Mapper is a finder of the entity, so the application always starts from the mapper.
- Entity should expose the functionality that is natural to be found on it.
- And entity makes use of (abstract or concrete) mapper for doing the concrete things.

In general, you must *model* your application without the data in mind. Then, design mapper to manage the transformations from objects to the data and vice verca.

### Now about validation

If the validation is the same in all the cases, then implement it in the entity, as that sounds natural to me. In most cases, this approach is sufficient.

If the validation differs and depends on *something*, abstract that something away and call the validation through the abstraction. One way (if it depends on the inheritance) would be to put the validation in the mapper, or have it in the same family of objects as mapper, created by the common Abstract Factory.